# Flash characters on OLED screen of Stellaris LM3S8962

Tags: c

I have an assignment of displaying A B C D on the OLED and then flash the letters A and C at a one-second rate and the letters B and D at a two-second rate. I have done as follows:

while(TRUE)

1/ display A B C D

2/ wait 0.5s, clear, and display B D

3/ wait 0.5s, clear, and display A C

4/ wait 0.5s, clear

Is it right? Can anyone instruct me in solving this problem with the smart solution?

Comment: This looks fine as pseudo-code. Do you have actual C code?

Comment: Also, I think you should remove the `flash` tag (your question has nothing to do with the flash player and co.

Comment: @lenz, actually, that is pitiful pseudo code, given the problem statement.  the total loop time is 1.5 seconds, which does not match the problem statement, and etc.

Comment: @user3629249, I share the same opinion with you, it is a raw solution. Could you help me find a better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement:

displaying A B C D on the OLED and then flash the letters A and C at a one-second rate and the letters B and D at a two-second rate.

The following pseudo code implements the problem statement

```
loop:
    clear and display "ABCD"
    wait 1 second
    clear and display " B D"
    wait 1 second
    clear and display "A C "
    wait 1 second
    clear and display "    "
    wait 1 second
end loop:
```

Comment: if by 'flash' it means a full off/on cycle in the allocated time, then the 'wait' can be changed to .5 second